# MySQL foreign key setup

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Newbie to dba and I'm working on a simple inventory database. This will list items of equipment, make, model, and status (active/inactive/lost).

I'm using MySQL Workbench, PhpMyAdmin, XAMPP, PHP, MySQL for this project.

I'm not sure if I am approaching this the correct way, hopefully somebody can give me some advice.

So far I have two tables - `items` and `status`.

`items`

```
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| itemId | invNo | make | model     | status |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 1      | 123   | HP   | 566       | 1      |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 2      | 432   | Dell | Precision | 1      |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 3      | 456   | Dell | Precision | 2      |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
```

`status`

```
+----------+------------+
| statusId | statusType |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | Active     |
+----------+------------+
| 2        | Inactive   |
+----------+------------+
| 3        | Lost       |
+----------+------------+
```

(You can see above that in my `items` table, there are two **Active** items, and one **Inactive** item).

In the front end application a table will list all of the items with their corresponding status (as text like below).

```
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| itemId | invNo | make | model     | status  |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 1      | 123   | HP   | 566       | Active  |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 2      | 432   | Dell | Precision | Active  |
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
| 3      | 456   | Dell | Precision | Inactive|
+--------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
```

Ideally I would like to be able to change status types in my `status` table, and have this update my `items` accordingly.

- one item can have only one status
- one statusType can be assigned to many items

Do I need to use foreign key relationships?

Any help or direction here would be great. I'd like to start off on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set up is correct. In the status table the statusId is a primary key and in your items table the status is a foreign key. This means it is a value which refers to a primary key in another table.

To add the constraint you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD FOREIGN KEY (status) REFERENCES status(statusId);
```

Comment: Now that the `items.status` is a foreign key it is constrained to only hold values which refer to a primary key value in the other table. In other words, if you are changing it from 1 to 2, then 2 needs to exist as an id in the other table. Could you please confirm whether that value is in the other table in the current database state?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a foreign key on items.status:

```
ALTER TABLE items
ADD FOREIGN KEY (status)
REFERENCES status(statusid);
```

Alternatively you could add:

```
[ON DELETE reference_option]
[ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html